# exim: different password for remote smtp relay smarthost

Tags: smtp, exim, smarthost

Currently I have my exim configuration set to send all e-mails using an external SMTP server. All users authenticate with my exim server with a local password and then the messages sent is relayed through a smarthost to a remote SMTP server, which uses a different login compared to the one used directly by the users connected to my exim server (running cPanel). Here's the current configuration:

```
remote_route:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = !+local_domains
  transport = remote_transport
  route_list = * remotesmtpserver.com

remote_transport:
  driver = smtp
  port = 587
  hosts_require_auth = <; $host_address
  hosts_require_tls = <; $host_address

remote_login:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = LOGIN
  hide client_send = : remote_username : remote_password
```

This all works well and as intended.

The problem is that I want to use a different remote_username and remote_password for a select group of users/senders. The login names (for my exim server) are full e-mail addresses, so I have added these e-mail addresses to a file /etc/differentlogin (i.e list of e-mail addresses separated by a new line).

I then tried following setup in the remote_login section:

```
remote_login:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = LOGIN
  hide client_send = ${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/differentlogin}{: different_username : different_passsword}{: remote_username : remote_password}
```

However this gives me the following EXIM error when attempting to send e-mails:

```
  == to@address.com R=remote_route T=remote_transport defer (-48): expansion of "${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/differentlogin}{" failed in mandrill_login authenticator: missing } at end of string
```

I attempted using $sender_address instead of $authenticated_id, but this gives me the same result.

I also tried replacing the variable to search for by a string i.e:

```
remote_login:
  driver = plaintext
  public_name = LOGIN
  hide client_send = ${lookup{email@domain.com}lsearch{/etc/differentlogin}{: different_username : different_passsword}{: remote_username : remote_password}
```

but I still get the same error.

To check the syntax of my conditional I tried to add the following to my remote_transport:

```
headers_add = X-SenderTest: ${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/differentlogin}{different}{normal}}
```

This works as expected and add the following header when sending an e-mail from the addresses/logins noted in the list /etc/differentlogin

```
X-SenderTest: different
```

Any tips?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that the client_send value is a number of values in a colon separated list. The solution to the problem is therefore fixed by formatting the value as below:

```
${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/differentlogin}{remote_username}{different_username}} : ${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/differentlogin}{remote_password}{different_passsword}}
```